# Scala: Convert nested value classes to Vector

Tags: scala

I have some type safe case classes that i want to turn into a vector:

```
case class Bdrms(underlying: Double) extends AnyVal
object Bdrms {
    implicit def toBdrm(x: Double): Bdrms = Bdrms(x)
}
case class Bath(underlying: Double) extends AnyVal
object Bath {
    implicit def toBath(x: Double): Bath = Bath(x)
}
// same pattern for many (20-30) other variables. sq ft, price, etc.
// and a parent case class

case class RealEstateDataPoint(bdrm: Bdrm, bath: Bath, sqft: Sqft,//)
```

one service needs to use these `Doubles` in the form of a `Vector`. if value classes were not used, i.e. if we just had
    `case class RealEstateDatePoint(bdrm: Double, bath: Double...)`
then something like the following works to iterate over the fields to create a vector:

```
def toVector(dataCC: RealEstateDataPoint): Vector[Double] = {
    val m = dataCC.productArity
    val vector = Vector(m)
    for (i<-0 until m) {
        vector(i) = dataCC.productElement(i).asInstanceOf[Double]
    }
    vector
}
```

But of course, the `asInstanceOf` type cast wont work with our value classes. Is there an idiomatic/efficient way to make the conversion to a vector?

Comment: what's `productArity` and `productElement`?

Comment: Why `Vector`? You can do this with a common super-type, but it won't be much safer. This problem seems more indicative of bad design.

Comment: Linear algebra libraries use vectors, not classes.

Comment: I liked the answer you selected, but I did work out a gist where I backed your real estate data type with a map. Not sure it would have any utility to you but i figured id provide a link: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e114cbc4b04b051b1293

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use structural typing:

```
dataCC.productIterator.map {
    case h:{ val underlying: Double } => h.underlying 
}.toVector
```

You might also consider making all the case classes inherit some trait:

```
trait HasUnderlying { val underlying: Double }
case class Bdrms(val underlying: Double) extends HasUnderlying
```

And then you can get the desired vector as:

```
dataCC.productIterator.map { 
    case h: HasUnderlying => h.underlying 
}.toVector
```

Comment: One must then be careful not to use a `Product` that contains something that is not `HasUnderlying`.

Comment: @m-z Definitely.  I agree with your above comment above that this may be emblematic of bad code design, except under special circumstances, since this is open to silly errors (e.g. misnaming the `underlying` variable) and run-time (instead of compile-time) errors

Comment: this is why im asking the question before the design :). The thought is simply that I am passing case classes around an akka cluster, and at some point i need to construct a dense vector (for Breeze) from the fields of the case class. The Case classes are constructed via datastore query and other http services.

Comment: also, not sure answering a question with "seems like bad code design" helps anyone ;)

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily bad code design.  I think it needs specific circumstances.  Needing a dense vector for breeze from case classes read via datastore seems to qualify, to me :)